# Find line number in a text file - without opening the file

Tags: linux, shell

In a very large file I need to find the position (line number) of a string, then extract the 2 lines above and below that string.

To do this right now - I launch vi, find the string, note it's line number, exit vi, then use sed to extract the lines surrounding that string.

Is there a way to streamline this process... ideally without having to run vi at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe using grep like this:

```
grep -n -2 your_searched_for_string  your_large_text_file
```

Will give you almost what you expect

-n : tells grep to print the line number

-2 : print 2 additional lines (and the wanted string, of course)

Answer (score 10):

You can do

```
grep -C 2 yourSearch yourFile
```

To send it in a file, do

```
grep -C 2 yourSearch yourFile > result.txt
```

Comment: This with `-n` is the most concise.

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep -n string file` to find the line number without opening the file.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `cat -n` to display the line numbers and then use `awk` to get the line number after a `grep` in order to extract line number:

```
cat -n FILE | grep WORD | awk '{print $1;}'
```

although `grep` already does what you mention if you give `-C 2` (above/below 2 lines):

```
grep -C 2 WORD FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with grep `-A` and `-B` options, like this:

```
grep -B 2 -A 2 "searchstring" | sed 3d
```

grep will find the line and show two lines of context before and after, later remove the third one with sed.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -n searchText fileName | cut -d: -f1
```

This would return only the line number, e.g. if text exists on line 10, then the output of the command would be 10, not what text is on the line. And, I am sure the original question expected exactly this.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to automate this, simple you can do a `Shell` Script. You may try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAL="your_search_keyword"

NUM1=`grep -n "$VAL" file.txt | cut -f1 -d ':'`

echo $NUM1 #show the line number of the matched keyword

MYNUMUP=$["NUM1"-1] #get above keyword
MYNUMDOWN=$["NUM1"+1] #get below keyword

sed -n "$MYNUMUP"p file.txt #display above keyword
sed -n "$MYNUMDOWN"p file.txt #display below keyword
```

The plus point of the script is you can change the keyword in `VAL` variable as you like and execute to get the needed output.